# Does systemctl daemon-reload need to be executed using root/sudo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

Does systemctl daemon-reload need to be executed using root/sudo? and does the same command apply to both Centos 7 and Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload

==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ====
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: neo
Password:
```

Yeah, I'd say so.
Unless you are doing it in a container with root privileges, pretty sure you need to have root permissions for anything related to systemd services.